# Ошибка создания виртуальной среды virtualenv

Tags: python-3.6, virtualenv

При создании виртуальной среды virtualenv python3 в windows 10, выпадает ошибка:

```
C:\Users\Вячеслав>virtualenv env

Using base prefix 

'c:\\users\\вячеслав\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36'

New python executable in C:\Users\Вячеслав\env\Scripts\python.exe

Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...

 Complete output from command C:\Users\Вячеслав\env\Scripts\python.exe - 
setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkgutil'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\users\вячеслав\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\вячеслав\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Вячеслав\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\вячеслав\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 712, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "c:\users\вячеслав\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 953, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "c:\users\вячеслав\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 904, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "c:\users\вячеслав\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 796, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))

OSError: Command C:\Users\Вячеслав\env\Scripts\python.exe - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Пробовал переустанавливать и питон и virtualenv, результат тот же.
Нашел похожий вопрос, там говорилось что virtualenv конфликтует с anaconda, удалил sublime text 3 c анакондой, результат тот же.

Comment: **1.** Обратите внимание на [**pipenv**](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) — на май 2018 это рекомендованный официально и наиболее совершенный метод создания виртуального окружения для Python. // **2.** Если нужно всё же virtualenv, обратите внимание на [**эту статью**](http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/python-pip-virtualenv-installation-on-windows/), используйте [**virtualenvwrapper-win**](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper-win/#description) // **3.** Скорее всего, конфликт с [**другой Анакондой**](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python), та, что для Sublime Text, ни причём. Спасибо.

Comment: Вероятно, проблема не в этом, но я не рекомендовал бы использовать кириллицу в имени переменной окружения `HOME`. У меня несколько проблем с разными программами из-за этого возникали. Т. е. рекомендовал бы заменить `C:\Users\Вячеслав` на что-то вроде `C:\Users\Vyacheslav`. Спасибо.

Comment: Большое спасибо, заработало, проблема была в кириллице!